# Write flink stream to relational database

Tags: database, jdbc, stream, apache-flink

I am working on a flink project which write stream to a relational database.

In the current solution, we wrote a custom sink function which open transaction, execute SQL insert statement and close transaction. It works well until the the data volume increases and we started getting connection timeout issues. We tried a few connection pool configuration adjustment, it does not help much.

We are thinking of trying "batch-insert", so to decrease the number of "writes" to the database. We come across a few classes which do almost what we want: JDBCOutputFormat, JDBCSinkFunction. With JDBCOutputFormat, we can configure the batch size.

We would also like to force a "batch-insert" every 1 minutes if the number of records does not exceed the "batch-size". How would you normally deal with these kinds of problems? My first thoughts is to extend JDBCOutputFormat to use scheduled tasks to force flush every 1 minute, but it was not obvious how it could be done.

Do we have to write our own sink all together?

Comment: Do you meant relational database instead of relationship database? Or did you mean a graph-database? In any case, your question is quite broad and possibly opinion-based.

Comment: Hi Mark, the persistent storage we are using is Oracle database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

JDBCSinkFunction does a flush and batch execute each time Flink checkpoints. So long as you are doing checkpointing, the batches won't be any longer than the checkpointing interval.

However, having read [this mailing list thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201811.mbox/%3CCAAdrtT2v2q7o_ZVHjK4CLUrqhGPeGhxP+B3cSSFGTh-npUcFww@mail.gmail.com%3E), I see that JDBCSinkFunction does not support exactly-once output.

Comment: That's good to know. I noticed the flush function in JDBCOutputFormat class reset the counter. If checkpointing process is also calling it, do we need to worry about synchronisation issue?